# Asp core doesn't enforce client certificate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, certificate, client-certificates, kestrel-http-server

I have an API app created using asp core. I'm trying to enforce use of client certificates as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-your-server-to-require-certificates).

I did tell Kestrel to require certificates in Program.cs:

```
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
{
    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o => o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
});
```

And I did add event handler in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCertificate(options =>
{
    options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnCertificateValidated = context =>
        {
        }
    };
});
```

When I debug the API running locally it still doesn't require any certificates. If I provide certificate anyway, the breakpoint in the event handler is never hit.

Comment: Do you make request(s) over HTTPS to your server?

Comment: yes, over https